# Minecraft PE Skin Reverting to default

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: skin UI]

I have the latest Minecraft PE version. I can't get my skin to work even tho I got it from a Minecraft skin app. It just keeps switching back to Steve... Thanks for reading I hope someone knows what's going on.

Comment: What is your skin? It may be invalid, therefore not working. PE uses the old skin system, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing your skin, then do not close minecraft pe and find games/com.mojang/minecraftpe/options.txt
Enter the options.txt and put this:

```
game_lastcustomskinnew:c18e65aa-7b21-4637-9b63-8ad63622ef01_Custom
```

Instead of:

```
game_lastcustomskinnew:c18e65aa-7b21-4637-9b63-8ad63622ef01_Steve
```

Then, return to the game.